# How to get input value from search field

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to get the input value entered in a search field and log it in the console. How can I achieve it? please someone guide me.
I am using the Ngx-admin theme. I want to get the value from the global search option.

HTML

```html
<i class="control-icon ion ion-ios-search"
       (keyup.enter)="submitSearch()"></i>
    <input placeholder="Type your search request here..."
           #input
           [class.hidden]="!isInputShown"
           (blur)="hideInput()"
           (input)="onInput($event)">
```

TS

```js
value: string;

submitSearch() {
   console.log(this.value);
  }
```

Comment: What's the current behavior exactly: it logs something wrong? Nothing at all? An error log somewhere? Also why using the `keyup.enter` on the icon and not rather on the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in many ways.

You can pass the value from the template to you method by naming your input on the template and passing his value in your typescript method parameters:

HTML:

```
<!-- I moved the keyup.enter event from your <i> element to the input -->
<i class="control-icon ion ion-ios-search"></i>
<input #searchInput placeholder="Type your search request here..." [class.hidden]="!isInputShown" (blur)="hideInput()"
    (input)="onInput($event)" (keyup.enter)="submitSearch(searchInput.value)">
```

Typescript:

```
submitSearch(value: string) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

You can alos use ngModel to bind your typescript property to the template input. Read the official documentation: https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel

EDIT: I added a short example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-example-cvpkkq

There is exactly what you need in the official Angular documentation: https://angular.io/guide/user-input#key-event-filtering-with-keyenter

Comment: Hey, i tried it. but it does not work. if possible, can you please provide me a working example. thanks

Comment: Sure: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-example-cvpkkq